# Reference to China in Manusmṛti?

Tags: history, india, manu-smriti

In his column [*What exactly is the Manusmriti?*](https://www.dailyo.in/lifestyle/hindus-manu-dharmashastra-manusmriti-vedas-devdutt-pattanaik-mythology/story/1/15412.html), Devdutt Pattanaik says the Manu mentions China. Which verse(s) is he referring to?

> Manusmriti was composed roughly around 200 CE (Common Era). We know this because **it refers to** Saka (North West tribes) and **Cheen (China)** who established contact with India around this time.

Comment: maybe you can ask *him* that ? there is a place to leave comments on that blog.

Comment: I usually upvote all questions that I'm answering but this time I have not because I don't agree with the assertions of the author.

Comment: @Rickross Which assertion? About 200 CE? Take a look at [this intro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PShlR.jpg) by Patrick Olivelle in his translation of Manusmṛti.

Comment: Yes about that one.. Yeah I know that Olivelle has tried to assign time periods of not only Manu Smriti but he did the same for various other Smritis. I use one of his books to write many answers here. But I don't agree with his arguments by which he arrived at those time periods. Not substantial arguments IMO and I hv read them. @sv.

Comment: Ok. What is the earliest date of Manu according to you? Whose translation are you using in the answer below. @Rickross

Comment: IMO one can't assign dates like that to Hindu scriptures. Regarding your other question I hv never checked till I saw your comment about who is the translator of the Manu Smriti I cite in answers. Checked now it does not mention any translator's name. It has all the verses in Sanskrit and their translations in English. The translator has written Ch as K all through out (e.g- Kina for China, Kandala for Chandala etc). So, this could be a hint for finding out who the translator is. @sv.

Comment: Unless it's your own translation, you are required to credit the author/translator in your answers. At least leave a link to it. If you are using the tr. from http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm then it must be George Bühler @Rickross

Answer (score 8):

The word "China", referring to a particular tribe, is found in Manu Smriti 10.44:

> 10.43. But in consequence of the omission of the sacred rites, and of their not consulting Brahmanas, the following tribes of Kshatriyas
>   have gradually sunk in this world to the condition of Sudras
>
> 10.44. (Viz.) the Paundrakas, the Chodas, the Dravidas, the Kambogas, the Yavanas, the Sakas, the Paradas, the Pahlavas, **the Chinas**, the
>   Kiratas, and the Daradas.
>
> 10.45. All those tribes in this world, which are excluded from (the community of) those born from the mouth, the arms, the thighs, and the
>   feet (of Brahman), are called Dasyus, whether they speak the language
>   of the Mlecchas (barbarians) or that of the Aryans

The relevant verse in Sanskrit is:

> PoundrakAsha chauda drAvidAh kambojA yavanAh shakAh |
>  PAradA
>   pahlavAsh **chinAh** kirAtA daradA khashA ||

So, according to Manu Smriti, all those tribes, including the China tribe, were originally Kshatriyas, but due to non-performance purificatory and sacred rites, they became *VrAtyas* and degraded themselves to the status of the Sudras.

Comment: So 'the China tribe' = China/Chinese or some other tribe close to India?

Comment: Chinese IMO, the verse also refers to Yavanas (Greeks), Sakas (Hunas) etc. @sv.

Comment: china tribe could also refer to "tibet" OR "tibet+east asia"

Comment: Yes possible because modern day Tibet is referred to as Maha china in Tantras @ArvindC

Comment: "China tribe, were originally Kshatriyas..." - true because chinese religion Taoism has similarities with indian religion like 'yin and yang' (puruSha-prakrutI of samkhya), vegetarianism (no onion, garlic, etc) etc.