# Which scripture is Devdutt Patnaik referring to when he says "Yagna is not a contract. Devata has no obligation"

Tags: identification-request, yajna

While explaining about Yagnas according to the Vedas, I have heard from elders that the Devata is bound by mantra (Devadhinam jagat Sarve mantraadhinam cha Devataa).

However, in an [article](https://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/buddhism/vedic-approach-to-desire.html) on his website, Devdutt Patnaik says the following :

> Yagna is not a contract. In a contract, there is give and take; there is obligation. Yagna is give in order to get. It is entirely voluntary. The devata has no obligation.

Which scripture is he quoting or referring to ?

Comment: But does  he say that he is following any particular scriptures while saying so? It can be just his opinion in this case. If his quote was " But the scriptures say or Manu Smriti or the Vedas say that Yajna is not a contract ... " then ur question would hv been a valid question.

Comment: @Rickross, in the article he mentions Vedas, Dharma Shastras, 'swaha' etc. all of which are definitely refer to scriptures.

Comment: Then u shd hv quoted everything relevant  in the question itself. From the small quote in ur question I can not make out that.

Comment: @Rickross, an article has to be read entirely to understand context. I've quoted only the relevant portion that I'm interested in. Users of this site can then spend 10 minutes reading the entire article and answer.

Comment: alrighty.. who are the 3 people who voted to close this as opinion-based? whose opinion am i asking for ? I'm strictly asking for scriptural reference. Maybe you should take a look here as well - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29924/which-verse-of-v%c4%81lm%c4%abki-r%c4%81m%c4%81ya%e1%b9%87a-is-devdutt-pattanaik-referring-to , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29846/reference-to-china-in-manusm%e1%b9%9bti

Answer (score 1):

Devdutt Patnaik (DP) gives his own explanation of Hinduism and Buddhism. **He does not care about any scripture.** For example, in the article quoted in the question he claims, 'Buddha focusses on the self'. That of course is obviously incorrect because Buddha says quite clearly in Majjhima Nikaya that his unique contribution to spirituality is the negation of the self. This is just one example of DP rejecting scripture.

Another example of DP's questionable assertion is the article posted below.

http://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/buddhism/the-hermits-smile-how-celibacy-non-violence-and-purity-work-to-establish-patriarchy-in-india.html

He blames celibacy, non-violence and purity for patriarchy.

The answer to the question is that DP's claims are not always backed by any scripture.

Comment: Rubbish is a strong word. Remember that there is [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) which applies for whole netwirk including our site and respect should be given for every individual. Moreover this is not answering the question. Edit the words which are offensive.

Comment: I made the necessary changes.